# Swift Mailer - multiple recipients not working

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have a problem with Swift Mailer, It seems easy, but I'm strugling with it for hours.
I need to send an email to multiple recipients.
This is a string I begin with (the content of $email->getRecipients() ):

```
// Just an example
first@gmail.com, second@gmail.com
```

First I remove all non-visible characters:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $email->getRecipients());
```

Then I add surranding quotes:

```
$addQuotes = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $string) . "'";
```

And remove empty spaces:

```
$recipients = str_replace(' ', '', $addQuotes);
```

Which gives me:

```
'first@gmail.com','second@gmail.com'
```

If I paste the string manually:

```
->setTo(['first@gmail.com','second@gmail.com'])
```

It works. But when I try to put variable like this:

```
$array = explode(',', $recipients);
...
->setTo($array)
```

Emails are not being sent.

When I do this:

```
->setTo([$recipients])
```

I get the error Address in mailbox given ['...','...'] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

I also tried:

```
foreach($array as $recipient) {
    $message->setTo($recipient);
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

Not working! But again, if I paste string directly, it works:

```
foreach($array as $recipient) {
    $message->setTo('first@gmail.com');
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

The code:

```
private function sendEmail($email)
{
    //$email->getRecipients() = 'first@gmail.com, second@gmail.com'

    $string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $email->getRecipients());
    $addQuotes = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $string) . "'";
    $recipients = str_replace(' ', '', $addQuotes);
    $array = explode(',', $recipients);

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($email->getSubject())    
        ->setFrom($email->getSender())
        ->setTo($array)
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'Emails/default.html.twig',
                array('body' => $email->getBody())
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    //foreach($array as $recipient) {
    //    $message->setTo($recipient);   
    //    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    //}        

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);           
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding quotes to your e-mail addresses? You should start with removing these. But all you really need is a `preg_split()` on your input string and a validation of each individual e-mail address after that.

Comment: Because SwiftMailer documentation says so: https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html (section Setting To: Recipients).

Comment: https://ideone.com/UpXhx1 thats basiclly what your doing, so end up with quotes as part of the email address you are trying to send to

Comment: Not really, the docs show an array of strings but the strings themselves are plain e-mail addresses, they don't include quotes.

Comment: Ok, works, thanks! If you want the up vote I'll glad to accept your answer